# How to display a string with new line character in a HTML page using Expression Language?

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

```
 <td>
      <span class="priority" 
        title="${fn:replace(result.priorityNoteValues,',','<br>')}"  
           onmouseout="tooltip.hide()">

         <img src="${path}/img/icons/priorityNote.png" 
              align="middle" width="15" height="15" alt="PN"/>
    </span>
 </td>
```

I get this:
**kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk**

I want to get this:

kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

if string exceeds 15 character, then next string will come to next row.

Is there anything I could do with the Expression language to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in an HTML element you just have to target it with CSS and set the `word-break` property to `break-all`.

Here is a good documentation about this :
[**CSS3 word-break Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Comment: not working .....                                                                                      <span class="priority" style="word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;" title="${fn:replace(result.priorityNoteValues,',',',')}"  onmouseout="tooltip.hide()">

Comment: But on the priority class, what properties have you given to that span?